# Flex 3 & Flash Player 10 Debug Version

Tags: apache-flex, flashplayer-10

I've got a Flex 3 app targeting Flash Player 9. Can I download the Flash Player 10 debug version and use it. Would I need to change any settings? (I don't want my app to target Flash Player 10).

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash 10 will play SWF files created in Flash 9 just fine, but if you really want to debug perfectly in Flash 9 you should stick with the Flash 9 debug version of the player.

Comment: Hi Robusto, thank you for the message. I screwed up and installed the regular (not debug) version of Flash Palyer 10. Do you know how to uninstall Flash Player 10 (without adversely affecting my project in some way), so that I can r-install Flash player 9 debug version? Thank you.